# Open new gnome-terminal from scripts and input vars from present script.

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, sh

```
#!/bin/bash

Dpath=/home/$USER/Docker/
IP=`sed -n 1p /home/medma/.medmadoc`
DockerMachine=`sed -n 2p /home/$USER/.medmadoc`
DockerPort=`sed -n 5p /home/$USER/.medmadoc`
DockerUser=`sed -n 3p /home/$USER/.medmadoc`
DockerPass=`sed -n 4p /home/$USER/.medmadoc`

if [ ! -d $Dpath ] ; then
mkdir -p $Dpath
else 
stat=`wget -O ".dockerid" http://$IP/DOCKER-STAT.txt`
for ids in `cat .dockerid`
do
if [ "$ids" == "$DockerMachine" ] ; then
gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'sshfs -p$DockerPort $DockerUser@$IP:/var/www/html $Dpath ; bash '
nautilus $Dpath
zenity --info --text "Mounted $DockerMachine"
exit
else
:
fi
done
zenity --info --text "No Such ID:$DockerMachine"
fi
```

> gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'sshfs -p$DockerPort $DockerUser@$IP:/var/www/html $Dpath ; bash '

this command opens up a new terminal but the problem is that it does not load vars like  $DockerPort  $DockerUser $IP $Dpath from this script.

How do I input the values in these vars from this script to the newly opened terminal ?

Thanks !

Comment: Change the single quotes to double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated before, you could try to use double quotes instead of single quotes around the `sshfs` invocation.

Single quotes in Bash are used to delimit verbatim text, in which variables are not expanded. Double quotes, in contrast, allow for variables expansion and command substitution (`$(...)`) to take place.

If you do use double quotes, beware of unintended side-effects (your username may contain a space, a dollar, a semicolon, or any other shell-special character). A cleaner approach would be to export the variables to the environment before calling gnome-terminal (and not forgetting to add double quotes around your variables *inside* the single-quotes), so that your code looks like :

```
export Docker{Port,User} IP Dpath
gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'sshfs -p"$DockerPort" "$DockerUser@$IP":/var/www/html "$Dpath" ; bash'
```

You may not want to pollute the environment with variables that will only be used once. If that is the case, instead of `export`ing them, you can use Bash's `declare -p` feature to serialize variables before loading them into a new environment (in my opinion, this is the cleanest approach). Here is what it looks like :

```
set_vars="$(declare -p Docker{Port,User} IP Dpath)"
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "$set_vars;"'sshfs ....'
```

Using this latest method, the variables are only visible to the shell process that runs the sshfs command, not `gnome-terminal` itself nor any sub-process run thereafter.

PS: you could read all your variables at once from the ~/.medmadoc file by using the following code instead of repeated `sed` invocations :

```
for var in IP Docker{Machine,User,Pass,Port}; do 
  read $var
done < ~/.medmadoc
```

This code makes use of the `read` builtin, that reads a line of input into a variable (in its simplest form).

PPS: That `stat` variable probably won't contain any useful information, since the output of wget was redirected by the `-O` flag. Perhaps you meant to store the result code of `wget` into stat, in which case what you meant was :

```
wget -O .dockerid ...
stat=$?
```